# Babel parser in react

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

So I'm really stuck here. I'm willing to edit babel-parser in react so no matter what I return in JSX it will wrap it with React.Fragment element. I ran npm eject in my cli to have access to babel-parser and I'm overwhelmed of where to start or what to edit :(

My goal is to compile this

```
import React from 'react'
const Element = () =>{
return (
<h1>It's now valid to</h1>
<h2>Return Multiple Elements</h2>
)
}
```

into this under the hood :

```
import React from 'react'
const Element = () =>{
return (
<React.Fragment>
  <h1>It's now valid to</h1>
  <h2>Return Multiple Elements</h2>
</React.Fragment>
)
}
```

And then it will be compiled normally. I would really appreciate any help or hints on where to start.
Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply add the fragment yourself (or the equivalent empty tag `<>.....</>` instead of modifyng the compiler?

Comment: It's an assignment I got to do so I can pass to the next level and I have a deadline tomorrow 